# NotifyDatasetChanged not working on a custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm trying to fill a ListView with a custom Adapter.
I want to use the NotifyDatasetChanged to refresh the layout, but it doesn't work.
I retrieve some JSON data from an HTTP request, and I manipulate the result string then I fill the ListView

What's wrong in my code?
**UPDATE THE CODE** (For the advice)

```
public class CalendarioFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Calendario> calenList;
    CalendarioAdapter adapter;
    String json;
    ArrayList<String> arrayId = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayData = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendario_layout, null);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listCale);
        listView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));

        calenList = new ArrayList<Calendario>();
        adapter = new CalendarioAdapter(getActivity(), calenList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        execQuery("query", "0");

        return view;
    }

    private void execQuery(final String query, final String taskId) {
        final MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(String output) {

                if (output == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nessuna connessione internet attiva!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    json = output;

                    try {
                        ParseJson();
                        calenList.clear();

                        String[] ids = arrayId.toArray(new String[arrayId.size()]);
                        String[] date = arrayData.toArray(new String[arrayData.size()]);

                        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                            Calendario calendario = new Calendario();
                            calendario.setId(ids[i]);
                            calendario.setData(date[i]);

                            calenList.add(calendario);
                            adapter.updateData(calenList);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, getActivity());

        asyncTask.execute(query, taskId);
    }

    private void ParseJson() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("risposta");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrayId.add(JO.getString("ID"));
            arrayData.add(JO.getString("DATA"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the CustomAdapterCode:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CalendarioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    final static String TAG = "sb.dl";

    public CalendarioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CalendarioAdapter");
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CalendarioAdapter.getView");
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendario_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.edId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edId);
            holder.edData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edData);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Calendario newsItem = (Calendario) listData.get(position);
        holder.edId.setText(newsItem.getId());
        holder.edData.setText(newsItem.getData());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView edId;
        TextView edData;
    }

public void updateData(ArrayList<Calendario> updatedData) {
    listData = updatedData;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: Well you are always using the same parameters so what if the data is same?

Comment: Please add the code for CalendarioAdapter

Comment: How? I can't in the comments

Comment: You should add code to your question and not by the comment. To do that press on `edit` button below your question and tags

Comment: Ok.. I've added the CustomAdapter code

Comment: I use this code in a TabLayout. Maybe the problem it's why the fragment is called before is visible to user?

Comment: Or maybe, tha'ts why I do "executeQuery" everytime I return to the tab?

Answer (score 1):

After these three lines

```
listData = new ArrayList<Calendario>();
adapter = new CalendarioAdapter(getActivity(), listData);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You should never *re-assign* `listData`. Once you do, the reference of the list within the adapter has become detached, and it no longer can be notified for updates.

So, instead, you need to `clear()`, then `addAll()` on the list.

For example,

```
ParseJson(); // You should really pass 'output' as a parameter here
listData = getListData(); // Don't re-assign
```

Do this instead, then notify

```
ParseJson();
listData.clear();
listData.addAll(getListData());
```

Alternatively, why call `listData.addAll(getListData());`? You already have this method which does the correct thing of clearing, adding, and notifying.

```
private ArrayList<Calendario> getListData() {

    listData.clear(); // Cleared
    String[] ids = arrayId.toArray(new String[arrayId.size()]);
    String[] date = arrayData.toArray(new String[arrayData.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        Calendario calendario = new Calendario();
        calendario.setId(ids[i]);
        calendario.setData(date[i]);

        listData.add(calendario); // Adding
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify

    return listData;
}
```

So, realistically, you only need these two lines in the AsyncTask (and again, should add `output` as a parameter of `ParseJson`, you don't need to save the `json = output`).

```
ParseJson();
getListData();
```

Comment: Sorry.. Always same result :(

Comment: I'm not sure you've followed my answer completely. I see in the update you still have `listData = updatedData;`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

`listData` is the variable inside of the `Cale` class. When you set new values to it the variable inly in `Cale` class is getting modified. The rest of the code where the duplicate of the data was set are not getting changed. In other words the data inside of the `CalendarioAdapter` is not updated when you are modifing the `listData` which is in `Cale` class.

**Solution:**

You need to pass the updated `listData` to adapter again after it was changed. In order to do that you need to create a method inside of your `CalendarioAdapter` adapter which will be responsible for updating the data inside of adapter and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Add this method to your `CalendarioAdapter` adapter:

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<Calendario> updatedData) {
    listDataInYourAdapter = newData;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now to use that method, in your `Cale` class replace this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with this:

```
updateData(listData);
```

Comment: @Simone Was my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

I solved!
That was a stupid thing!

In parseJson sub, I need to clear the arrays before to fill them!

```
private void ParseJson() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("risposta");

    arrayId.clear();
    arrayData.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            arrayId.add(JO.getString("ID"));
            arrayData.add(JO.getString("DATA"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reassign the list again-> this is not recommended behavior.
Here is the correct way how to do it:
Inside the adapter: `public void update(List<ItemMessage> updatedList){
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(updatedList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();}`

- Don't forget to do it using a Handler